# Unable to return errors created on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, responders

I'm using the gem [Responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) but I'm not able to show errors that I create on my models using `erros.add(:base, 'Error message')`.

On my controller, before the `respond_with @app`, I debugged the `@app` object and it **has** errors `@app.errors.any?` returns `true`

On my view, when I check the `flash` and `@app` objects, none has the error

App controller

```
# app_controllers.rb
def destroy
  @app = current_company.apps.find(params[:id])
  @app.destroy
  respond_with @app
end
```

App model

```
# app.rb

before_destroy :destroy_on_riak

# ...

def destroy_on_riak
  # SOME CODE HERE
rescue Exception => e
  errors.add(:base, I18n.t("models.app.could_not_destroy", :message => e.message))
  return false
end
```

App view

```
# apps.html.haml
-flash.each do |name, msg|
  %div{:class => "flash #{name}"}
    =content_tag :p, msg if msg.is_a?(String)
```

This is the @app object **before** the `@app.destroy`

```
"#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000004fa0510 @base=#<App id: 34, ...>, @messages={}>"
```

This is the @app object **after** the `@app.destroy`

```
"#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000004fa0510 @base=#<App id: 34, ...>, @messages={:base=>[\"Não foi possível excluir a aplicação: undefined method `get_or_new' for #<App:0x00000004f824c0>\"]}>"
```

I have removed what's inside the `@base=` for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

jefflunt is correct, when one calls `#valid?` it clears the errors array: see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4a19b3dea650351aa20d0cad64bf2d5608023a33/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L333

The validators are designed to **100% determine** the validity of your object, not when you add errors yourself for later use.

While ActiveRecord does override `#valid?`, it still calls `super`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4a19b3dea650351aa20d0cad64bf2d5608023a33/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L58

If you want to add errors and have them persist I recommend something like this:

```
def failures
  @failures ||= []
end

validate :copy_failures_to_errors

def copy_failures_to_errors
  @failures.each { |f| errors.add(*f) }
end
```

Then modify your `rescue`:

```
def destroy_on_riak
  # SOME CODE HERE
rescue Exception => e
  failures.push([:base, I18n.t("models.app.could_not_destroy", :message => e.message)])
  return false
end
```

I know this seems convoluted and I know there are even examples online where people use or recommend `errors.add(:base, ...)`, but it is not a safe way to store and retrieve errors for later.

---

Also, just a recommendation, but I advise you to rescue `StandardError` and not `Exception` unless you absolutely must. Out of memory errors and stuff like that are `Exception`s, but every normal error you would ever want to rescue should inherit from `StandardError`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The mystery seems to be either (a) you might not be calling the right method, or (b) the `.errors` hash doesn't contain what you think it contains.

#### Wrong method?

In your controller you're calling `@app.destroy`, but the method that adds the errors is called `destroy_on_riak`

Are you sure you don't mean to type this?

```
# app_controllers.rb
def destroy
  @app = current_company.apps.find(params[:id])
  @app.destroy_on_riak    # <= The offending line?
  respond_with @app
end
```

Or is there a `before_destroy` callback missing from your code sample that in turn calls `destroy_on_riak`? From the code included I don't see anywhere that the `destroy_on_riak` method ever gets called, so this is just a guess.

#### Unexpected contents of `.errors` hash?

If that's not the problem, then when `@app.errors.any?` is returning `true`, then at that point in the code print the contents of `@app.errors` to your log so you can see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The `destroy_on_riak` is called on a `before_destroy` as you thought (I've updated the question with this important detail). The `@app.errors.any?` returns true when I place a `debugger` after the `@app.destroy` and it get lost between the controller and view.

Comment: If you move the `debugger` line to be before the `@app.destroy` call, can you call it in the console and inspect the contents (and post the contents of the full hash). Maybe there's a clue there.

So: `@app.errors.inspect`

Comment: The question is updated with the debug **after** and **before**

Comment: Any other suggestion? :)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some hints:

*Hint 1*

Your form may be calling `valid?` on the `@app` object. The `valid?` method clears the `errors` array on the instance.

It is not correct to use the `errors` array/construct outside of the validations context. But this is MHO.

*Hint 2*

According to Responders gem (which I have never used in the past), your locale just needs to have the correct configuration. Example:

```
flash:
  actions:
    create:
      notice: "{resource_name} was successfully created"
    update:
      notice: "{resource_name} was successfully updated"
    destroy:
      notice: "{resource_name} was successfully destroyed"
      alert: "{resource_name} could not be destroyed"
```

Does it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the locale, it's correct. About the **It is not correct to use the errors array/construct outside of the validations context.**, what's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with @p.mastinopoulos on this.  This should really be handled with the builtin validations.  Sounds like you are in need of building a custom validator.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate

Try replacing your `before_destroy` with a `validate`:

```
validate :destroy_on_riak, on: :destroy
```

Haven't tried this, but if it doesn't work, you may want to consider creating a custom Validator as referenced in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll sure give that a try and report back.